# How can I change a Commander or ACU upgrade?

Tags: supreme-commander

While playing the Supreme Commander Forged Alliance campaign and after I have built an upgrade for my commander (or an ACU unit) the game appears to offer me the possibility of losing that upgrade and replacing it with a different upgrade for that part (chest or right/left arm) of the unit. When I select a different upgrade the game then warns me that choosing the new enhancement will destroy my existing upgrade. No matter which choice I make at that warning message the game doesn't actually remove/replace an already built upgrade.

Is it possible to change commander/ACU upgrades, and how do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should work. at least if you use "Forged Alliance Forever" community fixes.

Take a look in this tutorial where he changes the ACU upgrade.

Comment: So this is broken in the vanilla game?

Comment: I don't have the vanilla now, but I test in the forged alliance expansion , it didn't work.

I will try later to test it in the campaign using the FAF launcher (with community fixes to test)

Comment: Using the FAF launcher in forged alliance campaign it works. 

If you like the game I really recommend download the FAF forever launcher, it will fix a lot stuff and let you play online with others.